# How to remove previous text from a calculation?

Tags: python, kivy, code-assist

I have recently started learning Kivy and made a calculator app but I can't figure out how to remove the previous text from a calculation when a button is pressed for the next calculation and the text only gets removed when clear is used.

Here is the code https://github.com/Rakshan22/Calcy2 . So does anyone here know the answer to this question? Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Put the essential part of the code into the question, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I actually have to add something in my code but I can’t understand how to do it so there isn’t any specific part

Answer (score 0):

You should identify when the text is the final answer and reset the text before adding new one.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Window.size = (350, 450)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.textIsResult = false

    def clear(self):
        self.ids.input.text=""
        

    def back(self):
        expression = self.ids.input.text
        expression = expression[:1]
        self.ids.input.text = expression


    def pressed(self, button):
        expression = self.ids.input.text

        if self.textIsResult:
            self.ids.input.text = f"{button}"

        if "Fault" in expression:
            expression = ""
            self.textIsResult = false

        if expression == "0":
            self.ids.input.text = ""
            self.ids.input.text = f"{button}"

        else:
            self.ids.input.text = f"{expression}{button}"

    def answer(self):
        expression = self.ids.input.text
        try:
            self.ids.input.text = str(eval(expression))
            self.textIsResult = true

        except:
            self.ids.input.text = "Fault"

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

Comment: I am actually having a problem in identifying when the text is the final answer. So I need some help in that

Comment: you can just declare a variable in the self method.